# better way to notify an inner(nested) recyclerview adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an `Activity` that has a `RecyclerView` and a `RecyclerView.Adapter` (let's call it adapter1). inside of this `Adapter`, I have another `RecyclerView` and another `Adapter`(adapter2). What I want to do is that there might be some info passed to `onActivityResult` and needs to be passed to the inner adapter2. What I'm doing is creating a method in both adapters and chain them up from activity all the way to adapter2. I feel this way is a bit stupid. Is there any other way to achieve this? I did try EventBus but looks like I'm not able to subscribe a method in an adapter.

Thanks!

**Edited**

everything works fine. I'm just looking for a better solution if there's any. the complete code will be too massive to post, so I'll just post some snippet here.

```
Activity A {
    Adapter adapter1;

    onActivityResult() {
        adapter1.onEvent();
    }
}

Adapter1 {
    Adapter adapter2;

    public void onEvent() {
        adapter2.onEvent();
    }
}

Adapter2 {
    public void onEvent() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

yes, info will update the lists.

Comment: Show us what exactly you're doing that is not working ? Should the passed data to adapter2, make it update its rows ?

Comment: question updated. does it help to clarify what I'm trying to do?

Comment: seems ok to me.

Comment: yes, it does work. but because Activity has no ref to Adapter2, it needs to rely on Adapter1. i feel there might be another way to make things simpler. like passing the ref of activity to adapter2 and have adapter2 overrides `onActivityResult()`? I dont know. just that having activity->adapter1->adapter2 makes me feel there might be a better way to write this

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I am having similar issues of notifying data change for nested recyclerView adapter.